# Oracle VIEW - Convert VARCHAR2 to DATE and find MIN/MAX of DATE

Tags: sql, view, oracle11g

Data:

```
Field1  Field2  BEGIN_DT    END_DT
R1      R2      10012015    04082018
R1      R2      04092018    09302018
R1      R2      10012018    12319999
```

The DATES are in VARCHAR2 format and I have converted them using:

```
BEGIN_DT = to_char(to_date(BEGIN_DT,'MMDDYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
END_DT to_char(to_date(END_DT,'MMDDYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

My issue is that I'm trying to find the earliest BEGIN_DT (min) and the latest END_DT (max).

When I input the following into my VIEW, I am not getting the earliest BEGIN_DT

```
min(begin_dt),
max(end_dt),
```

I get 04/09/2018 which is not the earliest BEGIN_DT

But when I input this into my view, I get the min date, but in the wrong format

```
min(to_char(to_date(begin_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))),
max(end_dt),
```

I get:  01-OCT-15 instead of 10/01/2015

How do I find the min/max of Dates in the proper format of MM/DD/YYYY?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should also fix your data model. Storing DATEs in VARCHAR columns is a really, really bad idea

Comment: I totally agree.  It is very old and outdated and I'm tasked with cleaning it up.  yipee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
 min(to_char(to_date(begin_dt, 'MMDDYYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

or this one:

```
to_char(min(to_date(begin_dt, 'MMDDYYYY')), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

when converting a date to a string the default pattern of the date would be 01-OCT-15 so you have to include your own pattern on the syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the logic.   The first option worked the best for me.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select to_char(begin_dt, ‘mm/dd/yyyy’) as begin_dt, 
       to_char(end_dt, ‘mm/dd/yyyy’) as end_dt 
from (select min(to_date(begin_dt, ‘mmddyyyy’)) as begin_dt, 
             max(to_date(end_dt, ‘mmddyyyy’)) as end_dt 
      from table)
```